# Derivative of solutions to polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, polynomials

I'm looking for a way to compute the derivative of the solutions to a polynomial with respect to a parameter. Take for example the quadratic equation
$$x(a)^2+ax(a)+b=0,$$
where $a$ is a variable parameter and $b$ is assumed to be fixed. It has solutions
$$x_{\pm}=\frac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}$$
and therefore the derivative is
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x_\pm}{\mathrm{d}a}=-\frac{1}{2}\left(1\pm\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-4b}}\right).$$
Is there a way to directly deduce this result form the equation and not from the solution? Especially as this requires the equation to be analytically solvable, but the equation in question is of higher degree.

P.S.: I'm almost sure there is no such technique, but maybe someone has knowledge of one.

Answer (score 3):

You can get some of the way through implicit differentiation:

$x(a)^2 + a x(a) + b = 0 \implies 2x \frac{dx}{da} + a = 0 \implies \frac{dx}{da} = -\frac{a}{2x}$

Unfortunately, that means you still need to solve for $x$ in terms of $a$ if you want the expression to be completely free of $x$ terms.